# IE compatibility issues with multiple background images using css

Tags: html, css

Why wouldn't the below code work in ie?

```
background-image: url(../images/bg_top3.jpg), url(../images/gradient.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-color: #fff;
background-position: center top, left top;
```

Comment: You cant set two background image in one css id/class

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing?

Comment: @Nilesh http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ and for the OP, if you are testing on older IE, just use CSS3 Pie

Comment: It works in Chrome and Firefox @Nilesh

Comment: css3 pie doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: which version of ie are you using

Comment: Version 8 of internet explorer

Comment: @sephiith CSS3 multiple backgrounds are not supported in IE8, use CSS3 Pie for using CSS3 properties for older versions of IE http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20back

Answer (score 1):

you can use css3 pie to use multiple backgrounds in ie

```
#myElement {
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat #CCC; /*non-CSS3 browsers will use this*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#CCC) to(#EEE)); /*old webkit*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*new webkit*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*gecko*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*IE10 preview*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*opera 11.10+*/
background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*future CSS3 browsers*/
-pie-background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*PIE*/
}
```

more info can be found @ http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background

Edit:
You need to add the behavior property to the rule where you need to use pie behavior.

You can apply it to all tags by adding:

```
*{behavior: url(/PATH-TO/PIE.htc);}
```

But this comes with a **huge** performance cost. 
You are better off by adding a class `pie` to the elements where you need to use css3 PIE, and target it using:

```
.pie {behavior: url(/PATH-TO/PIE.htc);}
```

Comment: Does this require the behavior property too? The docs aren't exactly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try hack as like below for IE8
SEE LINK FOR DETAIL   http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_Multi_background_images__including_I-16839.html

/* Now lets make it IE8 Multi-background images */

```
#multipleBackgroundImages { 
   background-image: url(../images/lilys.jpg); 
   background-position: bottom right; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/lakeside2.png', sizingMethod='crop')"; 
   border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 0 1em; 
}
```